# Continuous on an interval implies continuous on every subinterval?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathcal{I} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Is this function continuous on every subinterval of $\mathcal{I}$?

**If yes, prove it. If no, give a counterexample.**

*I have been struggling with this question, but I have not come up with a sufficient answer. My intuition says yes, but there are plenty of functions out there , therefore who knows?*

Comment: You might find it easier to prove the contrapositive. If a function defined on an interval $I$ is not continuous on some subinterval of $I$, can it be continuous on $I$?

Comment: I guess that it can't. But you know maths contain so many traps, that I really don't know what to suppose. Do you have a specific example in mind , if this holds?

Comment: What is your definition of continuous?

Comment: Well at high school we don't usually use $\epsilon-\delta$ but I really don't care about that. So, let's do that using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Comment: What definition do you use then?

Comment: $$\left ( \forall \epsilon >0 \right )\left ( \exists \delta >0 \right )\left ( \forall x \in \mathcal{I} \right ): \left | x-x_0 \right |<\epsilon \implies \left | f(x)-f(x_0) \right |<\epsilon$$

Comment: Okay, if you want to prove the contrapositive, you'll need the negation of that statement---what is it?

Comment: Well the foreach becomes there exists and there exists becomes foreach. Thus the negation becomes: $$\left ( \exists  \epsilon >0 \right )\left ( \forall  \delta >0 \right )\left ( \exists  \in \mathcal{I} \right ): \left | x-x_0 \right |<\epsilon \implies \left | f(x)-f(x_0) \right |\geq \epsilon$$ Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $f$ is continuous on $I$, 
$$
\forall x\in I \ \ \forall \epsilon> 0\ \  \exists\eta>0 \ \ 
y\in I \ \ \& \ \ |x-y|<\eta\implies |f(x) - f(y)|<\epsilon
$$
It is a universal property:
$$
\forall x\in I \dots
$$
hence it is true for every subset of $J\subset I$:
$$
\forall x\in J \ \ \forall \epsilon> 0\ \  \exists\eta>0 \ \ 
y\in I \ \ \& \ \ |x-y|<\eta\implies |f(x) - f(y)|<\epsilon
$$

hence $f$ is continuous on $J$.

Comment: That's what I had in mind.(But was not so sure about it) Thank you all...